# Jinja doesn't render anything when extending layout template

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to display data on a page, but the page is completely empty.  I know the database has data in it, and I know the `query_db` function returns the correct results, but I can't figure out why the data isn't being rendered by Jinja.  What is causing this problem?

```
@app.route('/toto')
def toto():
    entries = query_db("select col1,col2 from toto where col1 = 'grand test'")
    return render_template('show_results.html', entries = entries)
```

`show_results.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <ul class=entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry }}</h2>
    <br>
    {% else %}
    <li><em>No entry here</em>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

`layout.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>microblog</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Microblog: <a href="/index">Home</a></div>
    <hr>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does layout.html have a block named `body` in it?

Comment: Hi @SeanVieira, nope. Let me put what I have in my `layout.html`

Comment: Not sure who liked my question but thanks ! 501 points !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja doesn't let child templates output anything that isn't in a parent template block.  (In other words, block names must match.)  Either change `block body` in your child template to `block content` or rename your `content` block in layout.html to `body` and things will work.

Comment: See also: [The Null-Master fallback trick](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#null-master-fallback)